# Changing notification text using FirebaseNotificationPushManger

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I'm trying to change the content of a push notification received from firebase.
This is the application class in the Android project:

```
public class MainApplication : Application
    {
        public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transer) : base(handle, transer)
        {
        }

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();

            //Set the default notification channel for your app when running Android Oreo
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                //Change for your default notification channel id here
                FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelId = "FirebasePushNotificationChannel";

                //Change for your default notification channel name here
                FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelName = "General";

                FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelImportance = NotificationImportance.Max;
            }

            //If debug you should reset the token each time.
#if DEBUG
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, true);
#else
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, false);
#endif
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.IconResource = Resource.Drawable.logogiusto;
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.Color = Android.Graphics.Color.Red;

            //Handle notification when app is closed here
            CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
            {
                //var hardware_token=Xamarin.Essentials.SecureStorage.GetAsync("hardware_token");
                //Interface inter = new Interface();
                //float share=inter.GetShareOnHardwareToken(hardware_token);
                FirebasePushNotificationManager.NotificationContentTitleKey = "foobar";
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(FirebasePushNotificationManager.NotificationContentTitleKey);

            };
        }
```

Basically, I need to change the notification content with some data that I can get only via the user app (until the session is expired)*.
I thought about dealing with it using tokens instead of topics but since the app requires sending notifications to users at the same moment, it might become bulky on my side.

I also tried using

```
FirebasePushNotificationManager.NotificationContentTitleKey = "foobar";
```

as you can see from the code above, but it simply does nothing and the content still is the one I choose on firebase.

One interesting aspect is that I get this on the debug window whenever I receive a push notification from firebase:

```
[FirebaseMessaging] Unable to log event: analytics library is missing
[FirebaseMessaging] Missing Default Notification Channel metadata in AndroidManifest. Default value will be used.
```

Although I cannot fully understand what is this referring to.

*If what I receive from firebase is *NEW NOTIFICATION FROM FIREBASE* it needs to become *NEW NOTIFICATION FROM ABC*

Comment: You may not set the meta name correctly. set it like  <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/notification_channel_id" />

Comment: Yep that seemed to solve the problem. Although there wasn't a strings.xml file in my Android project and I needed to create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the meta name correctly so the Default Notification Channel can be recognized like:

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id" android:value="@string/notification_channel_id" />
```