# How to display the image in the notification

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I recently used FirebasePushNotificationPlugin in my application and everything is fine...
But when I send a notification, the image is not displayed and all other texts are displayed
I've searched and tried but to no avail:
This is the link for the tool:
https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin
And this is my code:
**Andriod:**

```
[Application]
public class MainApplication : Application
{
    public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transer) : base(handle, transer)
    {
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();

        //Set the default notification channel for your app when running Android Oreo
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            //Change for your default notification channel id here
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelId = "GeneralChannel";
            //Change for your default notification channel name here
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelName = "General";
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelImportance = NotificationImportance.Max;
        }
        //If debug you should reset the token each time.
#if DEBUG
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, true);
#else
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, false);
#endif

        //Handle notification when app is closed here
        CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += Current_OnNotificationReceived;

    }

    private void Current_OnNotificationReceived(object source, FirebasePushNotificationDataEventArgs e)
    {
       
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(this, Intent);
```

In Backend I used FireBase Admin Plugin :

```
public async void SendToAllUser(Notification notification, Dictionary<string, string> MsgData)
        {
            var message = new Message()
            {
                Data = MsgData,
                Topic = "all",
                Notification = notification,
                Apns = new ApnsConfig
                {
                    Aps = new Aps
                    {
                        ContentAvailable = true,
                        MutableContent = true 
                    }
                }
            };
            string response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message);
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully sent message: " + response);
        }
```

Notification Controller:

```
[HttpPost("UserName={UserName}&Password={Password}&Key={Key}&Value={Value}")]
        public ActionResult<Notification> SendToAllDevice(string UserName, string Password, string Key, string Value, Notification notification)
        {
            int UserRole = URole.CheckUserRolee(UserName, Password);
            if (UserRole != 1)
            {
                return StatusCode(403);
            }
            var Dataa = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { Key, Value } };
            SendFCMessage.SendToAllUser(notification, Dataa);
            return Ok();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the key and value(image url) in FCM console and handle it with the service you write.

You can refer to this question https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/541284/xamarin-forms-firebase-notification-ui.html

And also here is a sample:https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/main/Firebase/FCMNotifications/FCMNotifications

**edit:**

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id" android:value="@string/notification_channel_id" />
```

Comment: I used plugin.FirebasePushNotification 
when notification Receve outPut Wrote :
[FirebaseMessaging] Unable to log event: analytics library is missing
[FirebaseMessaging] Missing Default Notification Channel metadata in AndroidManifest. Default value will be used.
[FirebaseMessaging] Unable to log event: analytics library is missing

Comment: Set the meta name correctly so the Default Notification Channel can be recognized like above shows

Comment: Thank you for the answer
But I'm still facing the same problem
And it does not display the image
I recently added this line to the Manafist
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id" android:value="FirebasePushNotificationChannel" />
But the image is still not showing up
And this line appears in the output:
[FirebaseMessaging] Unable to log event: analytics library is missing

Comment: refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70526592/changing-notification-text-using-firebasenotificationpushmanger/70573508#70573508

Comment: I Add That : 
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id" android:value="FirebasePushNotificationChannel" />

the message "Missing Default Notification Channel" no longer appear
But The Image in Notification Still not Showing

Idont know why?

output :

 [FirebaseMessaging] Unable to log event: analytics library is missing

Comment: maybe there something wrong in the package you are using ,you can post an issue there , or you can check offical doc with Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging package https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows